# Ubuntu Upgrade Tool

Tags: 12.04, installation, upgrade, 12.10

When I try to upgrade to 12.10 I get the standard screen offering the upgrade,
then the welcome to Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal screen
then when I accept that two files are loaded called the `Ubuntu Upgrade Tool`
then no further action.
Why won't the full upgrade initiate?
Note the PC has been fully updated in 12.04 and restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following command from terminal?

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Make sure you set Prompt to `normal` instead of `lts` in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`